# Yonah and Leviathan midrash

Tags: midrash, agada-stories-legends

Anyone know the source for some midrash about when Yonah is in the mouth of the fish and then they go to the Leviathan and Yonah shows him his bris and he runs away?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.10.9?lang=bi

Comment: @TheGRAPKE thanks